# Fake and genuine coins

Tags: strategy, weighing, coins

There are 14 coins, numerated from  1 to 14, and presented as an evidence at the court. The first 7 are fake coins, and others are genuine coins. Fake coins have all the same weight and they are lighter  than the genuine coins. How can an expert  prove that the first 7 coins are fake, and that other coins are genuine, using balance, in at most 3 weighings? 
( We don't know whether the genuine coins have the same weight, but if someone can solve problem in case when they have the same weight,  I would appreciate it.)

Comment: Does the jury already know that the first 7 coins are all the same weight? (My interpretation of the question as it stands: no, they don't.)

Comment: I suppose they don't know.

Comment: user122, do you know a solution to this question?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan that was exactly what I was going to ask.

Comment: I don't have a solution

Comment: Could you tell us where the problem comes from?

Comment: @user122 suppose I know and prove (I didn't) that the first seven coins are of weight 3 and the other seven are of weight 4, still I can't understand how I can convince the jury that the first 7 are fake..

Comment: @yanko That is a very good point. We should probably take the question to mean simply "how can the expert prove that the first 7 coins are all lighter than the other 7 coins, in three weighings, given that in fact the first 7 coins have equal weight" or something like that. (Though I don't see how the equal weights are actually helpful.)

Comment: That was also on my mind, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Sorry to repeat myself, but could you tell us where the problem comes from? Two reasons. First, I can't help suspecting that there may be some inaccuracy in how it's stated, and checking the original might help. Second, we do generally insist around here on giving credit where it's due. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution where all fake coins weigh the same and all regular coins weigh the same (and all fake are lighter).  Label the fakes ABCDEFG, regulars abcdefg.

Test A vs. a.  See that A < a, and therefore A is fake and a is real.

Test aBC vs. Abc.  See that aBC < Abc.  Since A > a, we have 1 unit of difference going to the left, so it must take at least two units of difference the other way to make the scale tilt to the right.  Thus, it must be the case that both BC are fake and both bc are real.

Test abcDEFG vs. ABCdefg.  See that abcDEFG < ABCdefg.  As above, this proves that ABCDEFG are all fake and abcdefg are all real.

If the real coins could vary in weight, then you could never conclude anything by weighing coins and seeing they are different, since that could mean they are all real.

Comment: Ah, ok you assume that the jury knows that all of the fake and real are of the same weight and now it make sense..

Comment: Well, that's a fact already in evidence, as it were.  No way to do this in three weighings if there can be varying weights in either set.